# Cancel file upload - listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“On file dialog cancel” event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285937/on-file-dialog-cancel-event-in-javascript)

Is there a listener for when a user clicks cancel instead of done on a file upload dialog box?

Comment: the browser one, the file upload one.

Comment: I do not have a "Done" and "Cancel" button in my browser. Maybe that answers your question already?

Comment: How do you upload files on forms then?

Comment: @user1013512 afaik there is no way to capture this. I just looked at the MDN and MSDN specs and they have no events firing when the user clicks cancel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the input upload tag can't do this.

I have had good experiences using [this 3rd party JS uploader](https://github.com/bencolon/file-uploader). It doesn't use Flash so is suitable for mobile devices also.

You can set:

```
onCancel: function(id, fileName){}
```

In the initial setup call. See the instructions on the Github page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to determine if the user clicked "Cancel" using the input="file" html element.

If you need more control over the file upload on a webpage, you can use [Flash like Gmail does](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/better-interface-for-uploading-gmail.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can check if the value has changed (e.g. the user picked a file) using a listener for the `change` event.

Simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<input id=f type=file>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function picked(){
    alert("Picked");                
}


$('#f').focus(function(evt){
    $(this).change(picked);   
});
```

↪ [View this example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xnmjw/)

Answer (score -3):

Most likely it depends on the browser. Some browsers might allow you catch this.  Other browsers might not. This is because HTML standard does not explicitly state how a file upload control should look like or how the file selection has to be implemented. It [just says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#file-select) that:

> This control type allows the user to select files so that their
>   contents may be submitted with a form. The INPUT element is used to
>   create a file select control.

Browser developers may choose how they allow you to select files. It may be a pop-up window, it may as well be a list of all files in your computer/device which you have to pick from.

[HTML5 defines](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#file-upload-state-%28type=file%29) the behavior a little better, but again it does not talk about file selection process.

Comment: this doesn't really answer anything.

Comment: @rlemon Well, the question asked _if_ there is a listener (or comparable behavior), not _how_ it should be implemented.