# Jquery file upload, choose file dialog, capture cancel button is clicked

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, upload

When the `click` event to select a file is triggered

```
$("input[type='file']").trigger("click")
```

the choose file dialog is opened.

What I need is to trigger the event when the cancel button of this choose file dialog is clicked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014384/cancel-file-upload-listener and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628544/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input

Comment: As always :-( - anyway, thx!